# jQuery - place the result of a .js file into a specific place in html

Tags: jquery, getscript, insertafter

I wish to place a widget on my site that has an embed code like

`<script src="http://www.external-site.com/widget.js?id=123" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>`

after a specific div.

I only want the widget to appear on a certain url that uses the same template as other pages so I'd like to use jQuery to check for a certain url and then render the widget in specific spot.

Why doesn't this work?

```
    $(function() {
        if ( document.location.href.indexOf('/url-to-check/') > -1 ) {
         $('#myDiv').after('<script src="http://www.external-site.com/widget.js?id=123" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>');
       }    
                });
```

In other words, why can't I use the script tags in the after statement?  How else can I achieve this?

Thanks